# How do I copy and paste from local machine?

Tags: virtualization, clipboard

I need to cut copy and or paste from a text file on my laptop into my VM.. since it does not (the vm) recognize my keyboard @ symbol.

Comment: Are using VirtualBox or VMware?

Comment: Please, tell us what VM software are you using.

Answer (score 0):

For VMware make sure that VMware tools are installed.

VMware Tools is a suite of utilities that enhances the performance and management of the virtual machine. Without the tools installed, your guest machine will lack the following benefits:

- High video resolution
- Adequate color depth
- Correct display of network speed
- Unrestricted movement of the mouse
- The ability to copy and paste and drag-and-drop files
- Sound<sup>VMware</sup>

For VirtualBox make sure that Guest Additions are installed.